# how to install "mod_uploadprogress" in lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd

I need to install "how to install" mod_uploadprogress "in lighttpd, if someone has already done or who can help me, I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I have got same problem in installing this some time back. You can refer this link [mod_uploadprogress](http://www.woyaozhai.com/2011/05/32) (but its in chinese you can translate this page to english) Good Luck :-)